# Why does laravel connect to mysql on console but not on api or web?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I've been struggling for days now on this crazy issue.

I'm using laravel 7 and i can run migration commands on the console on my live server easily without issue but whenever i make an api request or access a route that accesses the database i get the following error:

`` SQLSTATE[HY000] [1698] Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (SQL: select * from `users` where `users`.`deleted_at` is null) ``

This doesn't happen locally at all and i don't even know how to even begin to try and attempt fixing it.
Here's my .env config

```
APP_NAME=Laravel
APP_ENV=local
APP_KEY=base64:DbtYDJ+yQV63X30kyxfoCRpgAMkjDNOdDVPPShePNFo=
APP_DEBUG=true
APP_URL=http://localhost

LOG_CHANNEL=stack

DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=127.0.0.1
DB_PORT=3306
DB_DATABASE=laravel
DB_USERNAME=root
DB_PASSWORD=

BROADCAST_DRIVER=log
CACHE_DRIVER=file
QUEUE_CONNECTION=sync
SESSION_DRIVER=file
SESSION_LIFETIME=120

REDIS_HOST=127.0.0.1
REDIS_PASSWORD=null
REDIS_PORT=6379

MAIL_MAILER=smtp
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
MAIL_PORT=2525
MAIL_USERNAME=null
MAIL_PASSWORD=null
MAIL_ENCRYPTION=null
MAIL_FROM_ADDRESS=null
MAIL_FROM_NAME="${APP_NAME}"

AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=
AWS_DEFAULT_REGION=us-east-1
AWS_BUCKET=

PUSHER_APP_ID=
PUSHER_APP_KEY=
PUSHER_APP_SECRET=
PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER=mt1

MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY="${PUSHER_APP_KEY}"
MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER="${PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}"

JWT_SECRET=oO71aEHHOVlngmeYGV8mS4XrJV0ljCjbSC3BBKJRrgTq3r1OZwQbuE5r8LPhFnEY
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

try this and see

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
php artisan cache:clear
```